# get records from mysql table where datatime is less than current datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table named `TrackHistory` which tracks any change in the Table `User`. `TrackHistory` Table has a column `ChangedDate` of datatype DATETIME which records when change is made in Table `User`. I want to get all the rows from Table `TrackHistory` where `ChangedDate` columns contains date just less than the current dateTime

For eg

Table `TrackHistory`

```
Row_No.         ChangedDate            UserID       Marks
1             2016-02-08 08:45:34     5             40
2             2016-02-08 08:45:34     6             30
3             2016-02-08 09:12:34     5             50
4             2016-02-08 09:40:30     5             70
5             2016-02-08 09:40:30     6             60
```

Suppose in my system current time is 2016-02-08 10:10:20

Since 4th and 5th row is the last change made in the `TrackHistory` table. So Row 4th and 5th are rows where ChangedDate is just less than the current time.

So how can I write a mysql query to select rows whose ChangedDate is just less than the current date. In another word, how can I get only the last updated rows from `TrackHistory` table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just depends an what you mean by "just less that the current datetime"; you can define an interval.

```
SELECT * FROM TrackHistory WHERE ChangedDate < NOW() AND ChangedDate > DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 10 SECONDS );
```

See [MySQL NOW function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) and [DATE_SUB function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

Comment: `ORDER BY ChangedDate DESC LIMIT 2` so it gets only 4th and 5th as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The table that is mentioned above is a Test table. In real scenario, there could be more than 50 rows that can be updated at a time. Truly speaking, I do not know how many rows are getting updated at a time. So I can't use `ORDER BY ChangedDate DESC LIMIT 2`

Comment: Hi Ian, `SELECT * FROM TrackHistory WHERE ChangedDate < NOW();` query will return all the rows of the `TrackHistory` table because 'ChangedDate' will always less than current time in all the rows. I want to pick only the last updated rows of `TrackHistory` table.

Comment: Didn't know quite what you meant by 'just less than current' but updated answer to show DATE_SUB and how you can use it w/ a defined interval (be it seconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours, days ... ) :)

Comment: Thanks Ian, your query worked. But I can't implement your query in my application. Here is my whole app description : Table `User` can be updated anytime in a day. So `TrackHistory` table will get updated anytime in a day. But fetching rows from `TrackHistory` table is part of another application which run only once in a day and at a fix time. I can't change the query manually every day to get the last updated rows. So is there any way to get the last updated rows?

Comment: Since you know the query will run once a day, would `ChangedDate > DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY )` suffice? DATE_SUB can use any interval specified. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by 'last updated rows'.

Comment: `ChangedDate > DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY )` will not work for me. If you go through the example that I have posted in my question, you will find that all the rows are update on same day, but row 4 and row 5 are updated lastly. Suppose fetching of data from `TrackHistory` table is scheduled at 10:30:20 am everyday. So If the app runs on 2016-02-08, then it should pick only row 4 and row 5, because they are the last update in `TrackHistory` table

Comment: "Just updated" by what criteria? As @Prix said, adding `ORDER BY ChangedDate DESC LIMIT 2` would give you the last two updated. Otherwise, what are the criteria?

Comment: The table mentioned in the Question is a test table. It is just for clarifying my question. In real scenario, I do not know how many rows are getting updated at a time. So I cannot use that criteria.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by 'just updated'. DATE_SUB can be used for any time interval. Read the link and I'm sure you'll find your answer.